# Firebase SyntaxError when deploying functions

Tags: node.js, firebase

I started a firebase functions project last week and it all worked like a charm for the first couple of days. This morning however I started having this error whenever I run the `firebase deploy --only functions` command:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:16:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

I am now running the Firebase cli tools version 3.5.0 and Node 5.5.0

Anyone knows what's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok the problem was with the Node installation but in order to solve that I had to first update homebrew. Once I did that I could actually upgrade Node and the problem disappeared.

Comment: I don't believe. This is the real solution!